# In R how can I fill downwards for all rows which match one variable and don't match another

Tags: r

I can't find this answered elsewhere, apologies if it was, and please point me in the right direction

I want to test a large data set (so no loops), and for all rows which match one variable (say ID) then test if a second variable (say Time) is within 2 hours. I want to make a URN by combining ID and time.

If the time is within (less than or equal to) 2 hours I want to use the same ID as the original top row.

For all rows where the time difference is greater than 2 hours I want to start a new URN from that point forwards.

Might make more sense with data:

```
ID      Time      URN             URN_whichIwanttomake  Index
hawk    09:05     hawk_09         hawk_09               1
hawk    09:10     hawk_09         hawk_09               2
hawk    10:00     hawk_10         hawk_09               3
hawk    11:00     hawk_11         hawk_09               4
hawk    15:00     hawk_15         hawk_15               5
hawk    16:00     hawk_16         hawk_15               6
eagle   12:00     eagle_12        eagle_12              7
eagle   12:20     eagle_12        eagle_12              8
eagle   12:45     eagle_12        eagle_12              9
eagle   13:50     eagle_13        eagle_12              10
eagle   14:00     eagle_14        eagle_12              11
eagle   14:30     eagle_14        eagle_14              12
eagle   15:15     eagle_15        eagle_14              13
```

I've tried using vectors with logic statements in an if statement, I can get my logic to work and return the correct vector of TRUE / FALSEs, but I can't use this to overwrite the URNs

My code so far:

```
IndexShiftedBy1 <- dt$Index + 1               # ie a vector which starts at 2 and goes up to 14

if ((dt$ID[dt$Index] == dt$ID[IndexShiftedBy1]) # ie if the two IDs are the same
&  (dt$URN[dt$Index] != dt$URN[IndexShiftedBy1])) { # URN2 (ie time dependent) is NOT the same
dt$URN[IndexShiftedBy1] <- dt$URN[Index] } # overwrite lower row with upper row's value
```

Now firstly this doesn't work and secondly if it did then I'd have to run it multiple times as it just shifts the problem down a row!

Any help much appreciated, I'm clearly missing a useful function / need to write one myself, but this is above my level of knowledge at the moment

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? It would be nice to know your initial attempts.

Comment: just added what I've been doing with an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution. The key component is `zoo::na.locf` (not tidyverse), which fills `NA` values with the previous non-`NA` value.

```
library(dplyr)
# library(zoo)
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    URN_new = if_else(c(TRUE, `units<-`(diff(Time), "hours") > 2), URN_original, NA_character_),
    URN_new = zoo::na.locf(URN_new)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 13 x 5
#    ID    Time                URN_original URN_whichIwanttomake URN_new 
#    <chr> <dttm>              <chr>        <chr>                <chr>   
#  1 hawk  2018-10-26 09:05:00 hawk_09      hawk_09              hawk_09 
#  2 hawk  2018-10-26 09:10:00 hawk_09      hawk_09              hawk_09 
#  3 hawk  2018-10-26 10:00:00 hawk_10      hawk_09              hawk_09 
#  4 hawk  2018-10-26 11:00:00 hawk_11      hawk_09              hawk_09 
#  5 hawk  2018-10-26 15:00:00 hawk_15      hawk_15              hawk_15 
#  6 hawk  2018-10-26 16:00:00 hawk_16      hawk_15              hawk_15 
#  7 eagle 2018-10-26 12:00:00 eagle_12     eagle_12             eagle_12
#  8 eagle 2018-10-26 12:20:00 eagle_12     eagle_12             eagle_12
#  9 eagle 2018-10-26 12:45:00 eagle_12     eagle_12             eagle_12
# 10 eagle 2018-10-26 13:50:00 eagle_13     eagle_12             eagle_12
# 11 eagle 2018-10-26 14:00:00 eagle_14     eagle_12             eagle_12
# 12 eagle 2018-10-26 14:30:00 eagle_14     eagle_14             eagle_12
# 13 eagle 2018-10-26 15:15:00 eagle_15     eagle_14             eagle_12
```

`data.table` alternative:

```
library(data.table)
datdt <- as.data.table(dat)
datdt[,
      URN_newdt := zoo::na.locf(
        ifelse(c(TRUE, `units<-`(diff(Time), "hours") > 2), URN_original, NA_character_)
      ),
      by = "ID"]
```

Base R:

```
ave(dat, dat$ID, FUN = function(d) {
  d$URN_newave <- zoo::na.locf(
    ifelse(c(TRUE, `units<-`(diff(d$Time), "hours") > 2), d$URN_original, NA_character_)
  )
  d
})
```

Brief explanation: `zoo::na.locf` fills an `NA` with the most recently non-`NA` value:

```
zoo::na.locf(c("hawk_09", NA, NA, NA, "hawk_15", NA))
# [1] "hawk_09" "hawk_09" "hawk_09" "hawk_09" "hawk_15" "hawk_15"
```

Knowing that, the next step is to figure out how to assign `NA` to the new URN when the time difference is less than two hours. `diff(dat$Time)` is direct enough, though because it can return different units without warning, we need to envelope it in `units<-(..., "hours")` to make sure we get what we need.

Next step, `diff` returns the vector length minus 1, so we need to determine if we need to prepend or append, and should that added value be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. In this case, we always want the first within a group to be the original, so prepending `TRUE` makes the most sense.

---

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
ID      Time      URN_original    URN_whichIwanttomake
hawk    09:05     hawk_09         hawk_09
hawk    09:10     hawk_09         hawk_09
hawk    10:00     hawk_10         hawk_09
hawk    11:00     hawk_11         hawk_09 
hawk    15:00     hawk_15         hawk_15
hawk    16:00     hawk_16         hawk_15
eagle   12:00     eagle_12        eagle_12
eagle   12:20     eagle_12        eagle_12
eagle   12:45     eagle_12        eagle_12
eagle   13:50     eagle_13        eagle_12
eagle   14:00     eagle_14        eagle_12
eagle   14:30     eagle_14        eagle_14
eagle   15:15     eagle_15        eagle_14")
dat$Time <- as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), dat$Time))
```

I'm using "today" for the `POSIXt` for convenience. I suggest going with something `POSIXt`-like, but over to you for determining difference in time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look over this and test it out. Looks good - and I've heard of tidyverse and zoo::na.locf when I've been searching for answers, but wasn't sure how to use them. I will knuckle down and try it out!

Comment: The dplyr one not yet, and I'll try base R tmrw

Comment: I'm guessing that you are testing it on real (larger?) data and not just the sample, so if you find what may be breaking the `dplyr`-solution, can you update your sample data to trigger the failure?

Comment: Thanks r2evans, I didn't know about accepting. Have done so now - really appreciate your help.